# Does c# have a shorthand "something if (condition);" statement?

Tags: c#, if-statement, shorthand-if

Simple and short: does C# have a shorthand `if` statement similar to Ruby's?

```
return if (condition)
```

Comment: No, but `if (condition) return;` is the same length.

Comment: what about `return (condition) ? "this value if condition is true" : "this one if condition is false"`?

Comment: @Nitro.de This is about conditionally returning, not about returning different values depending on a condition.

Comment: @Lee Not about length, but readability / expressiveness. `return if (condition)` makes it clear since the first word that this line is for returning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it doesn't. The standard way is exactly the same length, so no such shorthand would be justified probably. Consider the usual syntax:

```
if (condition) return;
```

vs. a hypothetical:

```
return if (condition);
```

A possible reason for introducting such a 'reverse' syntax would be that the *primary* intent were expressed first. Because of left-to-right reading, then it would be easier to understand, leading to more readable code.

---

From a language design perspective, it would make sense using a different keyword such as `when` in order to prevent confusing bugs. Consider the following *two* lines of code:

```
return            // missing ; here
if (condition);   // no warning (except empty 'then' part)
```

should probably have been written as:

```
return;           // ; here present
if (condition);   // unreachable code warning here
```

From a character-saving perspective, it makes sense in `begin … end` language. A construct like this:

```
if condition begin
    return;
    end if;
```

would be significantly shorter and probably more readable if written as:

```
return when condition;
```

Comment: Not about length, but readability. `return if (condition)` makes it clear since the first word that this line is for returning.

Comment: @jj_ Yes, see my extended answer.